# How do I encrpyt JDBC password to store in application.properties with Spring boot

Tags: encryption, spring-boot

I have an application using Spring boot to generate a runnable jar.  I would like to encrpyt a SQL-Server password and store that in the applicaiton.properties file.  In the past, with a war file, I would run a java command to do the encrpytion and point it to the installation of weblogic to generate a hash which could be used in properties files.  Now, since I'm using embedded Tomcat, I don't have a server to run that command against, so how do I encrpyt a password under this scenario?

Currently, the only configuration I'm doing is setting the connection string in the app.properties file:

spring.datasource.url = jdbc:sqlserver://db####\dv:1111;databaseName=AAA;

spring.datasource.username = user_query

spring.datasource.password = [this is what I want to encrpyt]

thanks in advance